# Ansible AWX AMI/EC2 default username and password

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ansible

What is the default username/password on the [AWX AMI for EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00FQ1B1BK)?  `admin`/`password` is **not** working.

Comment: Why the down vote?  I honestly want to know if I violated a rule.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but questions like these that are very product-specific (especially when the product is very new and not well-known), are best addressed to product-specific support venues (IRC, mailing lists, etc.).

Comment: +1 this helped me, which is what matters. Using IRC from the other side of the world is almost always met with no replies, because everyone's asleep.

Comment: Glad I could help.  But it's better if you upvote than just leave a comment : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After speaking with the crew on IRC, you must login to the box via SSH and it will tell you the password.